# How can I add a horizontal scroll bar to a table only if it does not fit in the enclosing DIV?

Tags: html, css

I have a standard HTML table. I didn't set the width of the table so it's okay if it fits on the page. However when the table contents are too wide then they extend outside of the enclosing DIV. Is there a way I can make it so that a scroll bar appears only if it's too wide?

Note I tried to add "overflow: hidden" to the DIV but then it just cuts off the table and I cannot see any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `overflow:auto`.
Read & Test it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

Answer (score 1):

use `overflow-x: auto;` for horizontal scroll and `overflow-y: auto;` for vertical scroll and use `overflow: auto;` if both direction.

Answer (score 1):

Adding scroll bars only when necessary is the purpose of `overflow:auto;` in CSS and `Overflow: scroll;` will add them all the time, which probably isn't what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
.containingDiv {
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe `overflow: scroll` or `overflow: auto` ?

This set a scrollbar if the content is to big.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow: auto` on the div.

Note that it will only work is your div has a fixed width!

Answer (score 0):

You want like [`This`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/bLcnx/11/), This is also animate which is more helfull